# Get product by ID API - angular how does params work?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, service, components

I'm building the frontend for a fruit shop, and I was given an API to work with. My problem is: I can get the products from this link: https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/ with no problem, but I don't know how to access [https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/{{id}}](https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/%7B%7Bid%7D%7D) . How can I make it so that I can make a list of all of the products with the ids ?
I have this on my card-component:

```
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  productsList: any;
  productsIdList: any;
  listaids:[] | any;

  constructor(private productsService: ProductsService,private router: Router,) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productsService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.productsList = data.products;
    })
  }
```

and this on my service:

```
export class ProductsService {

  public baseUrl = "https://api.predic8.de:443/shop/products/";
  
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl)
  }

}
```

I've tried getting the product by id using this in my service:

```
  getProductById(id:number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
  }
```

and then this in the component:

```
  productDetails(id:number){
    this.productsService.getProductById(id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.productsIdList = data.ids;
    })
  }
```

but I don't think I'm doing it correctly
The thing is, on the data it doesn't say "id", but the numbers at the end of the link need to change so I can access the data. example: https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/1 ,https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/30 etc

Edit:
To clarify. My problem is I need code to access to the rest of the url, so https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/PRODUCTID . the product id should change and I should be able to get each product separately, and show all what's inside (name, price, and category).
thanks :)

on my html I wrote:

```
<div class="cards-container">
    
    <mat-card class="new-card"  *ngFor="let products of productsList">
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{products.name}}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
        <mat-card-content>product description</mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions align="end">
            <button mat-raised-button> a {{products.price}}</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
    </div>
```

and the products.name works fine, because it's getting it from https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/  , but the products.price no, because it should have the id at the end of the url. I think it has something to do with httpparams??

Comment: Not able to understand what you are trying to say or what problem you are facing right now/

Comment: Your code is fine, what error are you getting?

Comment: @VimalPatel I need to show the results of each ID in the html, so I don't know how to write that, as a ngfor but how to get each id

Comment: What is the error you are facing? There are tons of articles you can find on how to use *NgFor loop.

Comment: @VimalPatel I don't have any errors. I was able to do a ngfor for the products in https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/ , but I don't know how to write it so that the loop gets a new product every time and creates a new card, for example https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/1 , https://api.predic8.de/shop/products/2, etc . you know what I mean? I'll edit the question again so you can see the code

Comment: it's explained in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information). you define a path like,e.g.  {path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent}` and subscribe to `activetedRouter.queryParams`, see that you ask about `params[id]` -the "id" is the same that you use in your "path".

Answer (score 0):

Response revised.
I think I understand what you are asking. And with the code you have shown, you can do what you want with this code in the template.

Don't forget to import toPromise() I think it's from rxjs but it could be from rxjs-compat - I know that "catch" on promise is from rxjs-compat for rxjs v6. I you wish to use it. It's deprecated on rxjs v7 and will be removed on rxjs v8.

```
import {toPromise} from 'rxjs';
```

- **Alternative 1:** call productDetails service on the template

```html
<mat-card-actions align="end">
            <button mat-raised-button> a {{ async () => { let promise = productsService.productDetails(products.product_url.replace(parseInt("/shop/products/",""))).toPromise(); let detail = await promise; return detail.price; })() }}</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
```

Not the best but it should work. Make sure to set `productsService` as public.
That is, you can call directly the method in your component that accesses the service.
Calling an HTTP service on the template expansion isn't very good.
You should ask for a service that returns a list of products that includes the price and then accessing directly the price in the ngFor.
Unless the list of products is small, imagine calling the service 10 or 20 times to get the price? It's a lot of roundtrips.
That way you do a service call with one list in the response, instead of calling for each product.

- **Alternative 2** - best choice. Fill productDetails on Component side

To obtain the id you can also use, instead of the `replace` call, the getId method.
Added `console.log` call so you can see the product list on browser console. Use F12 or Ctrl-Shift-I to open it on Firefox, Edge or Chrome.
After testing remove line from code.
I changed code to use firstValueFrom which is the recomended solution from rxjs.

Service:

```
export class ProductsService {

  public baseUrl = "https://api.predic8.de:443/shop/products/";
  
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl)
  }

  getProductById(id:number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + id)
  }

}
```

Component:

```
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
        //...
        function getId(url) {
          var idarray = url.split("/");
          return parseInt(idarray[idarray.length-1]);
        }
    
        ngOnInit(): void {
    
        this.productsService.getData().subscribe( productList => {
          let i = 0;
          for(i = 0: i < productList.length; ++i) {
              let product = productList[i];
              
              // using promises to await for result - it's bad but works.
              let observableDetail = this.productsService.productDetails(this.getId(product.product_url)).firstValueFrom();
              let productDetail = async() => {
                 let d = await observableDetail;
                 return d; 
              }();
              // add detail to product list element
              product.detail = productDetail; 
          }
          // the list now has detail on it
          this.productsList = productList; 
          // remove console.log after testing
          console.log("For debug, productList: ", this.productsList);
        });
  }
```

Template:

```html
<div class="cards-container">
    
    <mat-card class="new-card"  *ngFor="let products of productsList">
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{products.name}}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
        <mat-card-content>product description</mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-actions align="end">
            <button mat-raised-button> a {{products.detail.price}}</button>
        </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I still can't get it to work, in which parts should I implement your code? thanks again